# sending email but eliminating 'L' in the string from python

Tags: python, mysql, email

My output is coming  : total records in staging table are **(3L,)**
I only want number n brackets and how can i remove L , 
Im converting query to str because i am not able to concanete part1 and msg

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import csv
import MySQLdb
import pysftp
import smtplib
import sys

#connection to Database
conn =  MySQLdb.connect(host="XXXXX", # The Host
                      user="XXXXX", # username
                      passwd="XXXXX", # password
                      db="XXXXX") # name of the data base
part1 = """From: XXXXX
To: To Person <XXXXX.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: SMTP HTML e-mail test
Toatal records in Staging Table inserted:
"""
sender = 'XXXXX'
receivers = ['XXXXX','XXXXX']

x = conn.cursor()
query = "select count(*) as toatal_records_inserted from fpwbs_feed_stg"
x.execute(query)
msg = ""
for row in x.fetchall():
    msg += str(row) 
msg=part1+msg
smtpObj=smtplib.SMTP('XXXXX', 25)
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get the first item in the tuple:

```
for row in x.fetchall():
    msg += str(row[0])
```

Comment: It would be better to just grab everything but the last character since the number could have more than 1 digit: `msg += str(row[:-1])`

Comment: @user2896976: it's in a tuple so this will just pull the whole number from the tuple.

Comment: Sorry didn't see it was in a tuple. Use `row[0][:-1]` then.

Comment: @user2896976: if you do `str(3L)` you get `'3'`

Comment: But if it has an `L` then it's already a string. And `3L` is not valid in Python, unlike C.

Comment: @user2896976: that's just how Python represents long integers. The `L` is just an indicator that what you're seeing is a long integer instead of a garden-variety integer.

Comment: @user2896976: `type(3L)` gives `<type 'long'>`

Comment: @user2896976: `str(3L)` gives `'3'`

Comment: for row in x.fetchall():
       msg4 +=str(row(L)) i used L it did not work it say L is not defined ,

Comment: for row in x.fetchall():
       msg4 +=str(row[0][:-1])  , i also used this but still getting L